# indexError, searching within

Tags: python

I am writing a program that will read a CSV file with data that looks like this:

```
"10724_artifact11679.jpg","H. 3 1/4 in. (8.26 cm)","10.210.114","This artwork is currently on display in Gallery 171","11679"
```

And write it into an HTML table. I only want the files that say, in the 3rd position, "This artwork is not on display".. but I've been having issues with this set of data

```
import csv

metlist4 = []

newList = csv.reader(open("v2img_10724_list.csv", 'r')) 
for row in newList:   
    metlist4.append(row)  

artifact_template = """<td>
    <div>
    <img src= "%(image)s" alt = "artifact" />
    <p>Dimensions: %(dimension)s </p>
    <p>Accession #: %(accession)s </p>
    <p>Display: %(display)s </p>
    <p>index2: %(index2)s </p>
    </div>
    </td>"""

html_list = []

count = 5794
for artifact in metlist4:
        if artifact[3] in ["This artwork is not on display"]:
                artifactinfo = {}
                artifactinfo["image"]=artifact[0]
                artifactinfo["dimension"]=artifact[1]
                artifactinfo["accession"]=artifact[2]
                artifactinfo["display"]=artifact[3]
                artifactinfo["index2"]=count    
                count = count + 1
                html_list.append(artifact_template % artifactinfo)
         else:
                pass

f = open("v3display_test.txt", "w")
f.write("\n".join(html_list))
f.close()
```

I get this error, but only when I run the entire metlist4...

```
  File "/Users/Rose/Documents/workspace/METProjectFOREAL/src/no_display_Met4.py", line 34, in <module>
    if artifact[3] in ["This artwork is not on display"]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

if I run just a section, for example metlist4[0:500], the error does not occur. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Instead of doing `for row in newList: metlist4.append(row)` just use the reader directly instead of `for artifact in metlist4:`.

Answer (score 3):

There is at least *one* row that doesn't have a 4th element. Perhaps the line is empty.

Test for the length, and print the row to test:

```
if len(artifact) < 4:
    print 'short row', artifact
```

If it is an empty line, just skip it:

```
if not artifact: continue
```

You are using a lot of verbose and redundant code; there is no need to build a separate list when you can just loop over the `csv.reader()` object directly, and there is no need to add an empty `else: pass` block either.

Idiomatic Python code would be:

```
artifact_template = """<td>
    <div>
    <img src= "%(image)s" alt = "artifact" />
    <p>Dimensions: %(dimension)s </p>
    <p>Accession #: %(accession)s </p>
    <p>Display: %(display)s </p>
    <p>index2: %(index2)s </p>
    </div>
    </td>"""

html_list = []

fields = 'image dimension accession display'.split()

with open("v2img_10724_list.csv", 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile, fields=fields, restval='_ignored')
    for count, artifact in enumerate(reader, 5794):
         if artifact and artifact['display'] == "This artwork is not on display":
              artifactinfo["index2"] = count    
              html_list.append(artifact_template % artifact)
```

This use a `csv.DictReader()` instead to create the dictionaries per row, a `with` statement to ensure the file is closed when done, and `enumerate()` with a start value to track `count`.